# Compiling Java Classes Together

Tags: java, compilation

I thought I new this, but when I create an object out of an class in a seperate file, it only compiles if that class is defined in the same directory, or if I import it from the library.  I assumed it used classpath to search for the included class files, but when I add a random directory to classpath(and only place that file there), it still complains that the class is not defined and won't compile.  Where does it know to look for classes at compile time?

Example

```
public class SomeClass {

public SomeOtherClass SoC; // If this class is not in library or same directory -- won't compile.

}
```

Comment: Have you got `import whatever.SomeOtherClass;` at the top of your source file?

Comment: if you have an import which has the path to that class, then it should not complain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// If this class is not in library or same directory -- won't compile
```

Correct. Your classes need to be in the classpath, or in a `.jar` that you specify.

When compiling you would use

```
javac -classpath .:/some/other:/another:/some/foo.jar
```

You then `import` whatever you need in your .java files (your code)

Answer (score 0):

Besides the import you also have to have folders on the classpath that represent the class' package.

Example:

Class `com.whatever.SomeClass` is located in `src/java/com/whatever/SomeClass.class`.
Now, the classpath should contain `src/java/` and from there the package `com.whatever` is looked up.

If the classes are in a .jar file, you'd put the jar in the classpath. Inside the .jar you'd again have `com/whatever/SomeClass.class` (note that .jar is basically a zip like format).